# Symbols not Found when include libpq-fe.h

Tags: c, postgresql

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PQclear", referenced from:
      _main in test-458ec8.o
  "_PQconnectdb", referenced from:
      _main in test-458ec8.o
  "_PQexec", referenced from:
      _main in test-458ec8.o
  "_PQfinish", referenced from:
      _main in test-458ec8.o
  "_PQntuples", referenced from:
      _main in test-458ec8.o
  "_PQresultStatus", referenced from:
      _main in test-458ec8.o
  "_PQstatus", referenced from:
      _main in test-458ec8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I am getting this error message when I try to create an executable.

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we cannot reproduce your issue based on what you have provided.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dynamic library usually requires two steps: including the header file and linking in the library.  On linux with gcc the latter would be:

```
gcc test-458ec8.c -o test-458ec8 -lpq
```

or even better via pkg-config:

```
gcc test-458ec8.c -o test-458ec8 `pkg-config --libs libpq`
```